# Orange backed wasp (UK)

Tags: bug-identification, wasps

I saw a huge (for the UK) wasp with a red/orange back which I have never seen before which I have been unable to identify. It was ca. 100% larger than the everyday wasp you see around middle England.

What type of wasp is it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a wasp, it's a type of hover fly. According to the [Nature Spot](https://www.naturespot.org.uk/species/volucella-zonaria) website it's called a *Volucella zonaria*:

> This is a hornet mimic and is one of our largest and most spectacular hoverflies which can be recognised by its yellow and black banded abdomen. It is chestnut on tergite 2 and also on the scutellum and much of the thorasic dorsum. The only similar species is V. inanis which lacks the chestnut areas and which has sternite 2 yellow rather than black.